"Error: Unable to activate keep awake" in react native app
I'm new to react native and I created an expo app that uses location and camera. I noticed that when I select "Only this time" instead of "While using the app" when asking for permission, whenever I lock the device, the app will reload and I will get the error Error: Unable to activate keep awake even if I'm not using keep awake and it is not installed. Is this something to do with permissions or the packages that I'm using.
Packages: expo-camera, react-native-maps
error
I tried installing expo-keep-awake and using it but still getting the same error.
